# How to Retrieve an resource:root-resource-id in SampleResourceFinderModule from request

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, xacml2, wso2-identity-server

i have a scenario in which i am sending resource:root-resource-id from request as below

```
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            Customer
        </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:root-resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            Customer
        </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:resource:scope" IncludeInResult="false">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
            Descendants
        </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>`
```

Now , i have to access resource:root-resource-id  in SampleResourceFinderModule as is if i access resource:resource-id :

```
if("Customer".equals(parentResourceId.encode())){}
```

Can you please tell me how i ca do this ?

Comment: Hi Naveen, before you get into the implementation specifics, you want to define your authorization requirements (plain old english) and work your way from there. In your example, what's your policy? What are your attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly and what is your exact question. I guess you are trying hierarchical resource profile with WSO2IS that is mentioned as [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/09/multiple-decision-profile-hierarchical-resources/).  It seems to be that you have written new extension by implementing the "PIPResourceFinder". Idea of this extension is to retrieve the children or descendants resources under the given root resource. Therefore in the XACML request you need to send the root resource and the scope (children or descendants).

Then root resource is identified by the "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"  attribute id. (not "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:root-resource-id" attribute id.. I guess [blog](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/09/multiple-decision-profile-hierarchical-resources/) post has some mistake. According to the scenario in the blog post, it may need to send the root resource with different attribute id).

Scope is identified by the "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:resource:scope" attribute Id.

Finally you can access the root resource in the "PIPResourceFinder" finder. Then you can return the child resources that is related with root resource. You can go through the sample implementation mentioned in [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/09/multiple-decision-profile-hierarchical-resources/) blog.

Comment: thanks a lot  asela . Let me be clear ,i have a scenario in which i have a service ,service is having multiple objects, Objects will contain Attributes . so now , i will create a XACML request which will contain  only the service , PIP has to find its objects and also attributes for each objects .   But in my current implementation of PIP with scope and resource-id i can only find the Attributes of  objects .  However , if i send servicename i must be able to find objects and also attributes within it.